# Highcharts Sunburst chart - What is the range of colorVariation.to values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Highcharts API reference explains that colorVariation.to is the ending value of color variation that is applied to the last sibling.
Demo example : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sunburst/

```
levels: [{
        level: 2,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels: {
            rotationMode: 'parallel'
        }
    },
    {
        level: 3,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: -0.5
        }
    }, {
        level: 4,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: 0.5
        }
    }]
```

When i set colorVariation.To = 0 for level 3, all the siblings at this level are shown in same color. Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/hqkk8ut5/

```
levels: [{
        level: 2,
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels: {
            rotationMode: 'parallel'
        }
    },
    {
        level: 3,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: 0
        }
    }, {
        level: 4,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: 0.5
        }
    }]
```

In my application, I want to configure the colorVariation.to value. 
I would like to know that what range of values should i allow?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the key to understand how `colorVariation.to` works is by analyzing two core functions:

**1. `variation` from sunburst.src.js**

```
        function variation(color) {
            var colorVariation = level && level.colorVariation;
            if (colorVariation) {
                if (colorVariation.key === 'brightness') {
                    return H.color(color).brighten(
                        colorVariation.to * (index / siblings)
                    ).get();
                }
            }

            return color;
        }
```

**2. `brighten` from highcharts.src.js**

```
        brighten: function(alpha) {
            var i,
                rgba = this.rgba;

            if (this.stops) {
                each(this.stops, function(stop) {
                    stop.brighten(alpha);
                });

            } else if (isNumber(alpha) && alpha !== 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    rgba[i] += pInt(alpha * 255);

                    if (rgba[i] < 0) {
                        rgba[i] = 0;
                    }
                    if (rgba[i] > 255) {
                        rgba[i] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        },
```

**Example:**

Les't assume that we have two siblings on the same level and their `colorVariation.to` is `0,5`. The base color for this level is `rgba(255,0,0,1)` (red). For the first sibling the index equals to `0` in `variation` function. So the value passed to the `brighten` function is `0` (`0.5 * (0 / 2)`). The next step is multiplying this value by `255` (maximum level of brightness) and adding it to each color component except **a**: **r**, **g** and **b**. So for the first sibling this value remains the same as `colorVariation.to`.

For the second sibling the value of alfa is `0.25` (`0.5 * (1 /2)`). `pInt(alpha * 255)` will return `63` (`pInt` works just like `Math.floor` in this case). So the final value will be **`rgba(255, 63, 63)`**. The values higher than `255` and `0` are corrected by two `if` statements.

---

In this case `Math.min(r,g,b)` is `0`, so the if we want to get maximum brightness for the last leaf the `alpha` should equal to `1` (all components (r,b,g) must have value of `255`).

If we solve the equation from `variation` function: `colorVariation.to * (1 / 2) = 1`
we will get `2` - the maximum value for `colorVariation` in **this case**. All values higher than this will work the same as if they were 2.

The value of `colorVariation` can be a negative number - it will make colors darker instead of brighter.

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Kulig